# Verify publisher domain for AAD multi-tenant app on tenant migration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We're moving an existing application registration from our corporate tenant (foo-corporate.com) to a new dedicated tenant (bar-app.com).

The process of moving the app registration requires to create a new app registration in the bar-app.com tenant.

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-configure-publisher-domain) article, we need to *verify the publisher domain* (foo-corporate.com) in the new dedicated tenant (bar-app.com).

This is necessary, as the user will otherwise see **unverified** as the publisher on the consent screen (see #5 on screenshot) instead of the publisher (foo-corporate).

The process to verify the publisher involves hosting a `microsoft-identity-association.json` on https://foo-corporate.com/.well-known/ to verify the publisher.

**Questions**

- Is there another way to verify the publisher foo-corporate.com for the new app registration in bar-app.com tenant? We're a large enterprise and our development team doesn't have access to the hosting of foo-corporate.com (public website), so we can't put the json file there. I assume this is the case for most larger enterprises.
- In case there is no other option, do we need to host this file permanently or is it only needed for a first verification and can be removed afterward?

**Update 1**

The question is about **publisher domain verification** and *not* [**custom domain verification**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain) as the first answer to this questions assumed.

**Sample Consent Screen**

[image: Application Consent]

Answer (score 1):

You can verify your domain in Azure AD by adding a custom domain.  You can verify it using any of the methods [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain), which include creating DNS records or placing a file on the site.  The file is only required while verifying the domain; It can be deleted after the status shows as verified.

Azure Portal -> Azure AD -> Custom Domains:

[image: Verify Custom Domain]

From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-configure-publisher-domain) page:

> New applications
>
> When you register a new app, the publisher domain of your app may be
>   set to a default value. The value depends on where the app is
>   registered, particularly whether the app is registered in a tenant and
>   whether the tenant has tenant verified domains.
>
> If there are **tenant-verified domains**, the app’s publisher domain will
>   default to the primary verified domain of the tenant. If there are no
>   tenant verified domains (which is the case when the application is not
>   registered in a tenant), the app’s publisher domain will be set to
>   null.

Adding a tenant verified domain gives you more verification options.  Verification ensures non-repudiation which is essential for Microsoft to display an application's publisher to an end user.

Without placing a file on a website for the domain (I don't have a website), these are the options available to me:

[image]

The first is the domain I verified through DNS, the second is the onmicrosoft.com default domain.  Using the onmicrosoft domain however will not suffice as it is an **Available** domain as opposed to a **Verified** one.

Comment: The question is about publisher verification and not about domain verification. Furthermore, verification of a domain is purely by DNS (no file involved - TXT is something different and not a file). I clarify in my question.

Comment: Please see my edit reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-configure-publisher-domain

Comment: This is the same link I'm referring to in my question and therefore not of help.

Comment: The first link is to the methods you have available to verify a custom domain and I've detailed how you would go about that.  You said you didn't have access to the site but didn't say you didn't have access to DNS so I've provided you with a second option.  This is all you have available.

Comment: Thanks anyway, but I think you're confusing the two concepts. Publisher domain verification is not the same as custom domain verification and I've asked for alternatives on publisher domain verification, besides the documented ways. Let's see if someone else has an idea. Otherwise we need to clarify how we get access to our public website. Thanks.

Comment: The article explicitly states that you can select a tenant-verified domain for your application.  This tenant-verified domain list is the custom domain list in Azure Active Directory.  I'm not confusing them: they are the same thing.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to verify one domain in two tenants. You're indicating that I should verify our corporate domain in our dedicated app tenant. This is of course not possible and therefore a different concept, and that is why it is a different approach.

Comment: That's correct you can't verify a domain while it is registered as a custom domain in another tenancy.  You will certainly need to take the file route.